# Transition Probability Matrix of a Markov Chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I can not find Transition Probability Matrix that adds up to 1 in the first row. Am I missing something ?

Here is the definition of problem:

```
An investor bought shares of a company at $30 per share. Currently the value of the
share is $31. The investor will sell the shares either as soon as he makes 10% or more,
or when the stock drops to $30. At the end of each trading day the stock gains $2 with
probability (w.p.) 0.1, $1 w.p. 0.3, remains the same w.p. 0.3 and loses $1 w.p. 0.3.

What is the probability of making at least 10% ?
```

Can someone point me the right direction ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you simply confused about what the question is asking? In fact, there is no question at all in your “question”. Are we to calculate the probability of the investor winning 3 dollars? In that case, your chain is the stock price and there’s an obvious transition matrix (which you have even described in the definition of the problem)

Comment: The problem is constructing the markov chain. When I define states as losing 1 dollar, staying same, winning 1 dollar and winning 2 dollars i face with following problem : when u put -1 dollars in first row you can go to -1 (stay same) 0 and  +1 dollars which adds up to 0.7 but my transition probability matrix does not have -2 if i add it too it must go to infinite states. Sorry for broken english i dont know if i can explain myself.

Comment: I’m very confused about what you’re saying. There are two confusions: 1) you have not defined your problem (what is it you’re trying to find?) 2) what is your state space (is it the space of all possible stock prices? In that case, the transition matrix is indeed infinite, but whether you’re interested in the entire matrix depends on your problem, doesn’t it?)

Comment: The problem is : What is the probability of making at least 10% ?. When i try to define problem as 4 state : 30 31 32 and 33, the probabilities outgoing from state 30 is adding up to 0.7 which doesn't makes sense. This is what i'm asking sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Now it makes perfect sense. Sorry for being late to answer. I hope it still helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define your states more carefully.

Let there be 4 states in the state-space S = {0, 1, 2, 3}. Let us introduce the idea of “unrealised” profit/loss (URPL), which is the amount you would have gained/lost, supposing you close all positions (i.e. sell all stocks) immediately. For example, in your problem, initially the stock is at 31 while the investor bought it at 30, so the initial URPL is 31 - 30 = 1.

Now note that you have set up a “limit order” which caps your URPL at 3 (or 4). You also have a “stop loss order” which caps your URPL at 0. After the URPL reaches these values, it **stops moving** because the investor will sell the stocks, *realising* his profits/losses. In terms of Markov Chains, these are **absorbing** states.

Now let’s describe the *finite* state-space S:

0: URPL = 0

1: URPL = 1

2: URPL = 2

3: URPL = 3 or 4

Now, can you set up the problem?